# Kafka Avro Int to date conversion using apache camel/groovy

Tags: date, groovy, apache-camel, avro

There is Avro int date formate like

```
"name":"BirthDate","type":["null","int"],"default":null,"logicalType":"date"}
```

A date logical type annotates an Avro int, where int stores the number of days from the unix epoch, 1 January 1970 (ISO calendar).

```
example: "BirthDate": -8364 or "BirthDate": 2320
```

How do I convert or calculate date for this using Apache Camel or Groovy script.

Answer (score 0):

So if you just want to calculate the date you just need the milliseconds since the epoch and you can pass that to any number of date representations in Java.  If you want Avro to deserialize it as a date that's a bit trickier issue which is very much an Avro documentation question.  (I'm not an avro expert).  But, here is how you can create several different types.  I'd suggest adding a getter for it like this:

```
class MyObject {

    int daysSinceEpoch

    ...

    long getMillisSinceEpoch() {
       TimeUnit.MILLISECONS.convert( daysSinceEpoch, TimeUnit.DAYS )
    }

    Date getDate() {
       new Date( millisSinceEpoch )

    LocalDate getLocalDate() {
        Instant.ofEpochMilli(millisSinceEpoch)
               .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate()
    }

    Calendar getCalendar() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        cal.setTimeInMillis( millisSinceEpoch )
        return cal
    }
}
```

Then just take you pick on the data type you want.